# Is EntityFramework performance affected by specifying information like primary key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Say I have this simple entity:

```
public class Person
{
    public int    PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name     { get; set; }
}
```

The entity framework can infer by convention that the `PersonID` field is the primary key. However, if I give the model builder this class:

```
public class PersonCfg : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public PersonCfg()
    {
        ToTable("Person", "Person");
        HasKey(p => p.PersonID);
    }
}
```

Would that improve startup performance? My thought was it might allow EF to do less reflecting and startup the app faster but I don't know how it works behind the scenes to know if it has any impact.

Comment: Well, you are correct that the configuration variant requires less reflection. However, IIRC that reflection is only done at application startup, hence the performance benefit is there only at startup time. Individual requests after startup are not affected by this.

Comment: Yes it is startup time when the model is generated that I am thinking about. I have no expectation of performance gains after the model is generated.

Comment: This might be an interesting thing to know but if you end up wanting to speed up the startup time of the application by a very small amount of time, you might want to read [this article](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) first.

Comment: Well I have no performance benchmarks, but I assume that the reflection is not that high you'd really notice it. Unless your model is very large (hundreds of models).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test this, you can use the DbModelBuilder class to build the model yourself and track the speed of the "Compile" step.

Here's my example code (LinqPad script):

```
void Main()
{
    // Initialize the overall system, but don't count the result.
    BuildC();

    DateTime startDateA = DateTime.Now;
    BuildA();
    DateTime.Now.Subtract(startDateA).TotalMilliseconds.Dump("A");

    DateTime startDateB = DateTime.Now;
    BuildB();
    DateTime.Now.Subtract(startDateB).TotalMilliseconds.Dump("B");
}

public class PersonA
{
    public int PersonAId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private void BuildA()
{
    var builder = new DbModelBuilder();
    builder.Entity<PersonA>();
    var model = builder.Build(new DbProviderInfo("System.Data.SqlClient", "2008"));
    model.Compile();
}

public class PersonB
{
    public int PersonBId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private void BuildB()
{
    var builder = new DbModelBuilder();
    builder.Conventions.Remove<IdKeyDiscoveryConvention>();
    builder.Entity<PersonB>()
        .HasKey(p => p.PersonBId);
    var model = builder.Build(new DbProviderInfo("System.Data.SqlClient", "2008"));
    model.Compile();
}

public class PersonC
{
    public int PersonCId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private void BuildC()
{
    var builder = new DbModelBuilder();
    builder.Entity<PersonC>()
        .HasKey(p => p.PersonCId);
    var model = builder.Build(new DbProviderInfo("System.Data.SqlClient", "2008"));
    model.Compile();
}
```

I get the result of 2.0004ms to 2.0009ms. Curiously, removing conventions made the operation take longer.

Comment: Yes, BuildB is faster but only when you don't try and remove the conventions. I suspect since you only have a single entity the overhead of removing the convention is enough to make it slower. With many entities though it might end up making it faster to remove it.